# Calling a Java method from a JavaFX webview

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, javafx

In my project I have an HTML document that is displayed in a JavaFx WebView. I have a Javascript function that should call the Java method getData (currently it only prints the passed variable so that I can confirm the data is being passed from the WebView back to the Java application):

```
    public void getData(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

This is how I am attempting to add the functionality to call Java methods into my WebView webpage:

```
    JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.getDocument();
    win.setMember("app", new Bridge());
```

And here is the JavaScript function that I'm using to call getData:

```
     function interOp(val){
        app.getData(val);
     }
```

This function is called on the onchange event on a `<select>` tag. The guides I have followed seem to do exactly this, however when I run my program nothing is printed on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a resolution for this issue: instead of using `webEngine.getDocument();`, which returns an `HTMLdocument` object, use `webEngine.executeScript("window");` which gives a window object.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create the object before passing it... so this:

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.getDocument();
win.setMember("app", new Bridge());"
```

becomes this:

```
Bridge bridgeREF = new Bridge();
JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.getDocument();
win.setMember("app", bridgeREF);
```

This came from a bug report I read here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170515

Otherwise, the javascript call seemed to work half the time... needed a refresh sometimes.  It was really odd.

Though my code is/was a little different... here's how I register the java class "JavaApp" with the JavaFX window:

```
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

  JavaApp appREF = new JavaApp(webEngine); 
  webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {

              if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                  JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                    win.setMember("app", appREF);  
            }

            }
        });
   //other code for loading html, listeners, etc...
   }
```

The reference to the class should be created outside of the anonymous listener, else the garbage collector might get it.  Which is what (I think) was causing the erratic behavior I was experiencing...  your java class may or may not need the reference to webEngine.. I use that for loading another url after sending a file.

I don't think it matters whether you use Window or Document... except that window might be more persistent depending on whether you use full page loads or not.

Comment: The `Platform.runLater` is not needed as the `ChangeListener` already waits till it's outside the main tick.

Answer (score 0):

I think it varies depending on how you call the Java method from the web page, I'm pointing out the events. I think the `onchange` and `onfocus` events are not supported, only mouse-related events. But I'm not really sure about that.

And about JSObject class, `webEngine.executeScript("window");` should work.

You can see a full working example from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113915/javafx-invoking-java-methods-using-javascript).

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

i saw that if i use approach

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.getDocument();
win.setMember("app", new Bridge());"
```

it's work but if i resize window, event is not catched.

I also needed to use

```
-javaagent:javaagent-shaded.jar
```

in my run command (i copied it from eclipse command) to use Java 11:

```
java \
-javaagent:javaagent-shaded.jar \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-p /home/odroid/Scaricati/TestFX/bin:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-base.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-controls.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-fxml.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-graphics.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-media.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-swing.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-swt.jar:\
/usr/share/java/javafx-web.jar \
-m TestFX/application.Main
```